# Trying to get a sortable list with sub menu working

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui

I have been working for the past couple days trying to figure out sortable lists. I am working on a project that will allow the user to order out a nav/menu by dragging the links to the place they want them including a sub menu ( dropdown ). I have gone through dozes of stackoverflow posts and Googled as much as I can. I have it somewhat where I want it but I cannot get it to alert the full string of ids from the main and sub menu. Ideally I want a serialized string of the whole thing that I can store in the database. Here is what I have, I have been mixing and mashing all day so I tried to strip out what I know isn't needed for this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

I use the Jquery UI for this along with Bootstrap 3.

```
<div id="example5">            
  <ul class="list-group">
      <li id="1" class="list-group-item menlink">11111</li>
      <li id="2" class="list-group-item menlink">22222</li>
      <li id="3" class="list-group-item menlink">33333</li>
      <li id="4" class="list-group-item menlink">44444
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li id="6" class="list-group-item menlink">66666</li>
          <li id="7" class="list-group-item menlink">77777</li>
          <li id="8" class="list-group-item menlink">88888</li>
          <li id="9" class="list-group-item menlink">99999</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="5" class="list-group-item menlink">55555</li>
    </ul>  
</div> 

<script>
  $("#example5 ul").sortable({
        connectWith: "#example5 ul",
        placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
    update : function(event, ui) {
         var order = $(this).sortable('toArray').toString();
        alert(order);

    }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An html element can not begin with a number.  You need to add some kind of text before the numbers in each li ID.

I changed just a little bit of your code.

```
$("#example5").sortable({
    connectWith: "#example5 ul",
    items: "li",
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
    update : function(event, ui) {
       var order = $(this).sortable('toArray').toString();
       var serial = $(this).sortable('serialize');
       alert(order);
       alert(serial);

    }
 });
```

[Here is a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/oumichaelm/VLd63/)

Comment: thanks for that. That seems to have solved the initial problem. It brings about another question maybe you can help me with. I wanted the serialized result so I could see the child when there is one. Basically the sub menu. Right now its just a string of numbers which I know is what I was trying to get and it helps. Any idea how to make it so it differentiates the parent/child in a serialized string?

Comment: You should work with the update method of the sortable function to build a map of the list items and checking each one for children. Or maybe you could add or subtract information to the ids that help keep track of the parent child relationship of the menu items.